# How to get summary() of specific column vector in R code?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, summary

I am practicing some basic commands in the iris dataset below. How can I get the summary of a specific column 'Sepal.Width'? I've tried a few things but no luck. I was able to get the summary of the entire dataset but not sure about a specific column?

```
summary(iris)
```

Results:

| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width |
| --- | --- |
| Min. :4.300 | Min. :2.000 |
| 1st Qu.:5.100 | 1st Qu.:2.800 |
| Median :5.800 | Median :3.000 |
| Mean :5.843 | Mean :3.057 |
| Min. :4.300 | 1st Qu.:5.100 |
| 3rd Qu.:6.400 | 3rd Qu.:3.300 |
| Max. :7.900 | Max. :4.400 |

I tried to use the below and got an error about atomic vector:

```
df <- iris
summary(df$Sepal.Width)

Error: Error in df$Sepal.Width : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I also tried this to try to convert the data frame to a vector to be able to use that operator but not sure what to do next?

```
data <- data.frame(as.list(vec))
```

What am I missing here? Is it even necessary to convert it from a data frame to a vector?

Comment: `df <- iris;
summary(df$Sepal.Width)` works for me.

Comment: Try clearing your workspace or restarting R, at some point you probably stored something  in `iris` . Or just check your environment, `str(df)` and `str(iris)` to get an idea why R is convinced you have atomic vector before $

Comment: Thanks a lot! l did in fact need to clear my workspace, it looks like I had something stored already that was causing the error. I was able to view this in my global environment. I will make sure I make use of that window the next time! My command works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use "ColSums" function in base R and specify the column name in squre brackects
colSums(Sepal.Width[2])